# XRDP remote sessions

Tags: remote-desktop, xrdp

Ive been googling for a couple days and haven't figured it out. I'm trying to connect via XRDP to Ubuntu mate on a PI2 from a Win computer. My issue is I can't load the same session that is loaded on the hardwired screen. I can connect to the same remote session but can't connect to the main session that was loaded with the computer, similar to how Teamviewer allows the same session that is seen between remote users and the person sitting in front of the computer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a limitation of XRDP at the moment.  Technically, you cannot connect to the console session.  As you have noticed, you can reconnect to the same remote session but you will not be able to connect to the console session (as far as I know)

You could use some tips and tricks in order to connect to the console session.  Basically, you could use the xrdp solution and instead of selection Xvnc-sesman option you could select the vnc any option... A full explanation on how to achieve this can be found in this [link](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5956)

You are technically connecting using VNC Software through the xrdp software.....

Hope this help
Till next time 
See ya